# App getting error while trying to report error

Tags: java, android

so I'm using the androidhive tutorial to make a server for my app and connect to it. I have it so the server will send back different messages depending on what was sent in but I'm getting an error with it and I can't figure out why. Here is the class that the error occurs in:

```
class CreateNewSpot extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewSpotActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Spot..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String longitude = inputLong;
        String latitude = inputLat;
        String pavement = spinner_pavement.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String traffic = spinner_traffic.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String environment = spinner_enviro.getSelectedItem().toString();
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", longitude));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", latitude));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pavement", pavement));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("traffic", traffic));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("environment", environment));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            switch(success){
            case 0:
                //name is empty!
                break;
            case 1:
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AllSpotsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
                break;
            case 2:
                //name has been taken
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name for spot has already been taken.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case 3:
                //server error
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "A server error has occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An unknown error has occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //just an unknown error
                break;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Now I'm purposely sending in data to get success==2 but it tells me my app unexpected error has occurred. Why is this? Is it because of the pDialog is still open? I tried putting pDialog.dismiss(); above but I still get the error. Sorry if this is a simple question and thank you in advance.

Tyler

EDIT:
Logcat:

```
    class CreateNewSpot extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewSpotActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Spot..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String longitude = inputLong;
        String latitude = inputLat;
        String pavement = spinner_pavement.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String traffic = spinner_traffic.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String environment = spinner_enviro.getSelectedItem().toString();
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", longitude));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", latitude));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pavement", pavement));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("traffic", traffic));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("environment", environment));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            switch(success){
            case 0:
                //name is empty!
                break;
            case 1:
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AllSpotsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
                break;
            case 2:
                //name has been taken
                error_msg = 0;
                break;
            case 3:
                //server error
                error_msg = 1;
                break;
            default:
                error_msg = 2;
                //just an unknown error
                break;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        switch(error_msg){
        case 0:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name for spot has already been taken.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "A server error has occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case 2:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An unknown error has occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }
 }
```

Comment: Could you please add the error message to your question? If it's an app crash then look at your app's logcat output. If you're developing using Eclipse you can find that in the DDMS perspective. It should be a bunch of red log lines starting with "Uncaught exception".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting **unexpected error** because you are showing Toast from doInBackground(), which you can't do. You never handle your UI from background in AsyncTask. Just remove your try-catch block from **doInBackground()** to **onPostExecute()** and it will work.

Comment: when I put the try-catch in onPostExecute() it wants it back in doInBackground(); and says unreachable catch and underlines JSONException e. Could I just make it so the error changes a global variable and then in onPostExecute it does the toast commands?